# Qt QFile / QTemporaryFile cannot read or write

Tags: qt, qfile

I have no idea why, but i can´t get the simplest example of QTemporaryFile to run... My real intent is to write data from QAudioInput into a temporary file before it is processed later.

After trying several times I realized that neither .read(), .readLine(), .readAll() or .write() would have any effect... The error string is always "Unknown Error" and it neither works for QFile or QTemporaryFile.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTemporaryFile>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTemporaryFile tf;
    tf.open();
    tf.write("Test");
    QTextStream in(&tf);
    qDebug() << "Testprogramm";
    qDebug() << tf.isOpen();
    qDebug() << tf.errorString();
    qDebug() << in.readLine();
    qDebug() << tf.readAll();
    tf.close();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The debug posts:

> ```
> Testprogramm
> true
> "Unknown error"
> ""
> ""
> ```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file. This has to be done on the file itself when there's no stream on the file, or using the stream when one exists. Also - `QFile` is a proper C++ class that manages the file resource. There's no need to manually close the file. `QFile::~QFile` does that job.

The following works just fine:

```
#include <QtCore>

int main() {
    auto line = QLatin1String("Test");
    QTemporaryFile tf;
    tf.open();
    Q_ASSERT(tf.isOpen());
    tf.write(line.data());
    tf.reset(); // or tf.seek(0)
    QTextStream in(&tf);
    Q_ASSERT(in.readLine() == line);
    in.seek(0); // not in.reset() nor tf.reset()!
    Q_ASSERT(in.readLine() == line);
}
```

The above also demonstrates the following techniques applicable to [sscce](http://sscce.org)-style code:

1. Inclusion of entire Qt module(s). Remember that modules include their dependencies, i.e. `#include <QtWidgets>` is sufficient by itself.
2. Absence of `main()` arguments where unnecessary.
3. Absence of `QCoreApplication` instance where unnecessary. You will get clear runtime errors if you need the application instance but don't have one.
4. Use of asserts to indicate conditions that are expected to be true - that way you don't need to look at the output to verify that it is correct.
5. Use of `QLatin1String` over `QStringLiteral` where ASCII strings need to be compared to both C strings and `QString`s. Implicit ASCII casts can be a source of bugs and are discouraged.

   `QLatin1String` is a constant (read-only) wrapper, designed to wrap C string literals - thus there's no need to make `line` additionally `const`, although in real projects you'd want to follow the project's style guide here.